# How to get Cumulative sum of Employee Count for Financial Year?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below.

| Financial Year | Start Date of Month | Branch | Department | Region | Employee Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 01/05/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 25 |
| 2021 | 01/04/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 20 |
| 2021 | 01/04/2021 | Branch2 | Dept B | R1 | 15 |
| 2021 | 01/07/2021 | Branch2 | Dept B | R1 | 10 |
| 2021 | 01/07/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 20 |
| 2021 | 01/10/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 10 |
| 2021 | 01/12/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 15 |
| 2021 | 01/01/2022 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 05 |
| 2021 | 01/01/2021 | Branch2 | Dept B | R1 | 10 |
| 2022 | 01/05/2022 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 20 |
| 2022 | 01/04/2022 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 10 |

I'm trying to get cumuative sum of Employee Count with respect to Month, Branch, Department, Region for each Financial Year. The sample data consist of FY2021. I have data from FY 2018. The Starting Month of Finacial Year is April. So addition of value has to reset for each Financial Year. The output would be as below

| Financial Year | Start Date of Month | Branch | Department | Region | Employee Count | Running Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 01/04/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021 | 01/05/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 25 | 45 |
| 2021 | 01/07/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 20 | 65 |
| 2021 | 01/10/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 10 | 75 |
| 2021 | 01/12/2021 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 15 | 90 |
| 2021 | 01/01/2022 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 05 | 95 |
| 2021 | 01/04/2021 | Branch2 | Dept B | R1 | 15 | 15 |
| 2021 | 01/07/2021 | Branch2 | Dept B | R1 | 10 | 25 |
| 2021 | 01/01/2021 | Branch2 | Dept B | R1 | 10 | 35 |
| 2022 | 01/04/2022 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022 | 01/05/2022 | Branch1 | Dept A | R1 | 20 | 30 |

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to better explain what you have and what you want to achieve. After rereading 3 times, I have no idea. You want to get the cummulative sum of what? Do you want it aggregated per month or per month, branch, department and region? If the latter, it seems you already have that in your first table.

Comment: Hey @ErroneousFatality, I'm trying to calculate cumulative sum of Employee Count per month, branch, department and region. Apologies, I couldn't exactly put my intentions in words. Kindly check the output table

Comment: isn't this just sum and group by?

Comment: The published date is not in mysql date format *yyyy-mm-dd' so to be clear please confirm the published date is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: `SUM(..) OVER (..)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum(EmployeeCount) Over(partition by ... order by..)` as below mention for your example:-

**[Click here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EbxWhYzd)**

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (
FinancialYear VARCHAR(4),
StartDateofMonth DATE,
Branch VARCHAR(40),
Department VARCHAR(40),
Region VARCHAR(40),
EmployeeCount INT
);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO TBL VALUES
('2021','2021-01-04','Branch1','Dept A','R1','20'),
('2021','2021-01-05','Branch1','Dept A','R1','25'),
('2021','2021-01-07','Branch1','Dept A','R1','20'),
('2021','2021-01-10','Branch1','Dept A','R1','10'),
('2021','2021-01-12','Branch1','Dept A','R1','15'),
('2021','2022-01-01','Branch1','Dept A','R1','5'),
('2021','2021-01-04','Branch2','Dept B','R1','15'),
('2021','2021-01-07','Branch2','Dept B','R1','10'),
('2021','2021-01-01','Branch2','Dept B','R1','10'),
('2022','2022-01-04','Branch1','Dept A','R1','10'),
('2022','2022-01-05','Branch1','Dept A','R1','20');
```

---

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(EmployeeCount) 
             OVER (PARTITION BY FinancialYear,
                                Branch 
                       ORDER BY FinancialYear,
                                Branch,Department,
                                StartDateofMonth) AS RunningTotal 
FROM TBL;
```